# Parsing a text file into fields using multiple delimiter types

Tags: c#, parsing, file-io

I'm attempting to parse log files from a chat using c#, the problem I'm running into is that it's not really designed for parsing as it doesn't use standard delimiters.  Here's an example of a typical line from the file:

```
 2010-08-09 02:07:54 [Message] Skylar Morris -> (ATL)City Waterfront: I'll be right back 
 date time messageType userName -> roomName: message
```

The fields I'd like to store are:
Date and Time joined as a DateTime type

messageType

userName

roomName

message

If it was separable by a standard delimiter like space, tab, or comma it would be fairly simple but I'm at a loss on how to attack this.

---

As a follow up, using this code as a template:

```
List<String> fileContents = new List<String>();
string input = @"2010-08-09 02:07:54 [Message] Skylar Morris -> (ATL)City Waterfront: I'll be right back";
string pattern = @"(.*)\[(.*)\](.*)->(.+?):(.*)";

foreach (string result in Regex.Split(input, pattern))
{
   fileContents.Add(result.Trim());
}
```

I'm getting 7 elements (one empty before and after) the 5 that are expected.  How can I rectify this?

```
foreach (string result in Regex.Split(input, pattern)
        **.Where(result => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))**)
{
   fileContents.Add(result.Trim());
}
```

Ok, managed to resolve it with the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that old adage about "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."?

well, in this case, you really do need regular expressions.

this one should cover you in this case:

```
([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2} [\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}) \[([\w]+)\] ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+) -> (\([\w]+\)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+): (.*)
```

you should really test it though. I just threw this together and it may be not handling everything you could see.

Comment: I thought regular expressions would be the answer, it's just an area I have little experience in.  I will try it and report back.

Comment: if you want to spend some time to learn and experiment, check this out: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ there are better tools, but I dont know what OS you use. also, I recommend you check out what 'groups' are in regular expressions, because the above expression uses them, and you'll need to see how that works to make use of it.

Comment: +1 for the adage :), i've seen my fare share of regex questions on this board that do not require regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.*\[(.*)\](.*)->(.+?):(.*)
```

It uses the fact that message is in square brackets []
name is between [] and ->
room name is between -> and :
and message is everything afterwards. :)

Comment: I like yours. its much simpler to understand/explain and probably more robust for that reason.

Comment: @Oren, thank you. i try to keep it simple (because i don't know all the commands that you've just used in yours hehe)

Comment: I recently started using a bunch of visualizing tools (regexhibit on the mac), it's opened my mind to a lot of neat tricks I didn't know about. simple is almost always better though.

Comment: ah, too bad i'm on windows and have to do with online regex matching. alot of times i give simple `.*` answers but ppl seem to like the more expressive answers. i just realised if there are hypens in names, then your match probably won't pick that up in the name. also your roomname makes specific requirements based on the only example given. the advantage is you'll pick up badly formatted messages.

Comment: According to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, there is a problem with this pattern.  If the message field (the last group) contains a : inside of it, the regex skips the first : and instead stores everything after -> into the 4th group until the last : in the message, storing everything after that into the 5th group.

Comment: good point, not knowing the message requirement does make it harder to know how to match it but i've changed it to a lazy search. now we just have to hope the room name doesn't have `:` or we'll all be in trouble!